# Question from the proof of the Prime Number Theorem

Tags: analytic-number-theory

My question is pretty trivial, but I just wanted to ask about something I can't see at all.

In the proof of the PNT supplied in [these notes](https://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2014/3118/11/anntrhb.pdf), it is asserted that when $|t| \ge 2$ $$O(\log^9(|t|)/|t|^2)=O(|t|^{-3/2})$$ on page 39. I cannot for the life of me see why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I heard somewhere that $\ln t=O(t^\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, or at least something to that effect. Perhaps that'll help?

Comment: I'm trying to see if that's a result I can prove right now, but my efforts are coming up a little short! Thank you!

Comment: Well, $\ln t=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \frac{t^\varepsilon-1}\epsilon$, which might have relevance here. (I don't know a whole lot about Big O.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be shown through l'Hopital's rule that $$\frac{\log^9(|t|)}{|t|^{1/2}} \to 0$$ as $|t| \to \infty$.

This means that $\log^9(|t|) = o(|t|^{1/2}) = O(|t|^{1/2})$. Hence $$\frac{\log^9(|t|)}{|t|^2} \le C \frac{|t|^{1/2}}{|t|^{2}} = C \frac{1}{|t|^{3/2}}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I had completely forgotten L'Hopital's rule existed.

Comment: No problem. I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\log (|t|)=O(|t|^{1/18})$, so that
$$
\frac{\log^9 (|t|)}{|t|^2}= O\left(\frac{|t|^{1/2}}{|t|^2}\right)=O(|t|^{-3/2}).
$$

Comment: Where does the statement that $\log |t| = O(|t|^{1/18})$ come from? That's what I'm failing to see. I've tried and failed to show this.

Comment: The logarithm is growing more slowly than $t^{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$ . Just take $\epsilon=1/18$

Comment: @hert3583 More specifically: $\ln t\le\dfrac{18}et^{1/18}$, with equality iff $t=e^{18}$, roughly 65,659,969.1373.

Comment: Proof: Start with the familiar inequality $e^x\ge x^e$ (if you're not familiar with that one, try to prove it!) and substitute in $x=t^{1/18}$. Rearrange.